# How to use mysql_coldiff

Tags: mysql, database, compare

I'm now trying to compare the data of two databases, actually I'm doing a loop test which will generate 500,000 rows of data in two databases, and then I have to compare the discrepancy of the two databases, I tried to write a Java class to do the comparison but it's very difficult for me. I found this mysql_coldiff tool from stackoverflow and tried to follow the example in the webpage http://rossbeyer.net/software/mysql_coldiff/examples

Does anyone knows how to run this command？ “prompt > mysql_coldiff -d test -i ID -n COLDIFF_A COLDIFF_B”    I don't know what prompt mean here.

Thank you.

Comment: [_The documentation is right there_](http://rossbeyer.net/software/mysql_coldiff/docs0), and the  "the prompt" is any shell you desire.

Comment: @Wrikken the link is broken

Comment: Ah, trailng 0, [here it hould be without typos...](http://rossbeyer.net/software/mysql_coldiff/docs)

Comment: Thank you, I used "./mysql_coldiff -d test -i ID -n COLDIFF_A COLDIFF_B" and successfully run mysql_coldiff. but now I'm receiving another error message: "install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC,  .......   Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module hasn't been fully installed  " I'm figuring out how to make it right.